# Creating Macro for Copying data from one sheet to another,calculating the difference between dates in excel

Tags: vba, excel

The below mentioned data is for door access in a company where in we need to find the number of hours spent by a employee in office.

A employee can come in the office and swipe in and swipe out multiple times and all these details are register in the excel in non sorted order for all the employees.

I have a excel containing multiple columns

First two columns A,B are merged cells having date in this format(2015/01/25  7:27:30 PM).

The third column C has Access information having multiple entries for the below values(Entry/Exit).

For example

```
Column A Column B            Access Employee ID    Employee Name
==================================================

 1. 2015/01/25  7:27:30 AM      Entry     111          XYZ 

 2. 2015/01/25 7:30:30 AM       Entry     333           ABC 
 3. 2015/01/25  8:30:30 AM      Exit      111          XYZ
 4. 2015/01/25  9:30:30 AM      Entry     111          XYZ 
 5. 2015/01/25  9:30:30 AM      Entry     444          PQR

 6. 2015/01/25  10:30:30 Pm     Exit      333          ABC 
 7. 2015/01/26  7:30:30 AM      Exit      333          ABC
```

And so on.

Please note that the same employee can have multiple swipe in and out's throughout the day and will be clobbered among other employees information
The Goal is to as below
1) Copy the data from one sheet to another for the employees having spent time less than 9 hours for a specific day.

Here is the sample code that i have written it is work in progress

```
Sub HoursList()

  Dim cell As Range
  Dim cell1 As Range

  Dim NewRange As Range
  Dim NewRange1 As Range

  Dim MyCount As Long

  Dim ExistCount As Long

  Dim ExistsCount As Boolean

  Dim temp As Long
    Dim MyCount1 As Long


  Dim wsh As Worksheet, i As Long, lngEndRowInv As Long
  Set wsh = Worksheets("Standard Door History          ")
  'Set cell = Range("A1")

  ExistCount = 0
  ExitsCount = False

  MyCount = 1

MyCount1 = 1





i = 12
lngEndRowInv = wsh.Range("P" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row




'----For every cell in row G on the  Data sheet----'

For Each cell In wsh.Range("C12:D9085")

 If cell.Value = "Entry" Then


      'ExistCount = ExistCount + 1

     If MyCount = 1 Then Set NewRange = cell.Offset(0, -1)
      '----Sets up a new range to copy all data from the row if column in that row contains the value in question----'
Set NewRange = Application.Union(NewRange, cell.EntireRow)

     MyCount = MyCount + 1
End If



Next cell


For Each cell1 In NewRange

   If cell1.Value = "Mayur" Then

    If MyCount1 = 1 Then Set NewRange1 = cell.Offset(0, -1)
      '----Sets up a new range to copy all data from the row if column  in that row contains the value in question----'
Set NewRange1 = Application.Union(NewRange1, cell.EntireRow)

     MyCount1 = MyCount1 + 1

End If
Next cell1

If ExistCount > 0 Then

      NewRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Test").Range("A3")

  End If

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes.but none of it is covering the whole requirement.Also I am new to macros and have very little knowledge about the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very rough version that you could use in VBA. It needs refining and error trapping, and future proofing, but it does what you want it to. It takes data from the active sheet and current adds it to the second worksheet. The date for looking up is in cell N1 of the first sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyNine()

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim DateToFind As Variant
Dim CellDate As Variant
Dim Count As Integer
Dim cel As Range
Dim DateRange As Range
Dim StaffID As String
Dim TimeStamp As Double
Dim StaffSummary As Object
Dim DS As Worksheet
Dim SS As Worksheet
Dim SSRow As Integer

LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'You may wish to turn this into an input instead
DateToFind = Range("N1").Formula
Set DS = ActiveSheet
'You may wish to change this
Set SS = Sheets(2)
SSRow = 2

'Get a range containing all the correctly dated cells from the dataset
For Each cel In Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells
    CellDate = Left(cel.Formula, InStr(1, cel.Formula, ".") - 1)
    If CellDate = DateToFind Then
        If DateRange Is Nothing Then
            Set DateRange = cel
        Else
            Set DateRange = Union(DateRange, cel)
        End If
    End If

Next

'Create a summary dictionary of all staff IDs and their time spent in the office where 1 = 1 day

Set StaffSummary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For Each cel In DateRange.Cells

    StaffID = cel.Offset(0, 3).Value
    'These may need to be updated depending on your entry in the 'Entry/Exit' column
    If cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Entry" Then
        TimeStamp = -cel.Formula
    Else
        TimeStamp = cel.Formula
    End If

    If Not StaffSummary.exists(StaffID) Then
        StaffSummary.Add StaffID, TimeStamp
    Else
        StaffSummary.Item(StaffID) = StaffSummary.Item(StaffID) + TimeStamp
    End If

Next

'Copy the titles from the data sheet
SS.Range("A1:E1").Value = DS.Range("A1:E1").Value

'Copy the appropriate rows across using the dictionary you created
For Each cel In DateRange.Cells

    StaffID = cel.Offset(0, 3).Value
    If StaffSummary.Item(StaffID) <= 9 / 24 Then 'This is 9 hours so copy across
        SS.Range("A" & SSRow & ":E" & SSRow).Value = DS.Range(cel, cel.Offset(0, 4)).Value
        SSRow = SSRow + 1
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to change this code so that it can calculate the the hours spent on weekly basis instead of daily basis.For example each employee is expected to complete 45 hours in a week.Can you please help with this.

Comment: You can use one of the methods here to create a week number function: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WeekNumbers.aspx then instead of setting DateToFind to be the date in N1, set it to the week number. Then you'll need to set CellDate to be the week number of the date that it currently is, rather than the date. This should then create the array that you need.

Comment: Thanks.I managed it in some other way but appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Excel's inbuilt abilities before VBA, especially if you are new to VBA. This will involve adding additional columns to your input sheet though which you can hide, but may not be ideal for your situation. It could also get quite slow as there are some large calculations, but it does depend on your original data set.

I would suggest the following (although there will be a lot of variations on it!):

1) Create a summary table for the particular day.

- Create a date column in column F which is =TRUNC(A2) and copy down the table.
- In M1 have your input date - e.g. 2015/01/25
- In column L list all the unique Staff IDs
- Below the date in M, use a SUMIFS formula and time formatting to determine how many hours each person spent. In M3 for example `=SUMIFS($A:$A,$D:$D,$L2,$C:$C,"Exit",$F:$F,$M$1) - SUMIFS($A:$A,$D:$D,$L2,$C:$C,"Entry",$F:$F,$M$1)` then formatting as `hh:mm:ss`.
- In column N, use `=M2<TIME(9,0,0)` and drag down to work out if that individual has spent less than 9 hours in the building on that day.

You should now have a table showing all the staff and how many hours they spent in the building on that day, and a TRUE or FALSE whether they spent less than 9 hours.

2) Create your additional columns to pull the data to another sheet

- In Column G, determine whether the entry is for the date in question (in cell `M1`) using `=F2=$M$1` (should give a TRUE or FALSE)
- In Column H, determine if that individual has spent less than 9 hours (from the summary table) using `=INDEX(N:N, MATCH(D2, L:L,0))`
- In Column I, determine whether that entry should be copied across using `=AND(G2, H2)`
- Finally in Column J, determine which entry this is to copy across using `=IF(I2, COUNTIFS($I$1:I2,TRUE),"")
- Copy each of these down to the bottom of the table (you can hide them later)

3) Create your table on the next sheet for copying down - I have called my original worksheet "Data" and my second one "Copy"

- In column A, use `=ROW()-1` to create a sequential list of numbers
- In column B, use `=MATCH(A2, Data!J:J,0)` to find out which row of data from the original table is being copied across
- In column C, use `=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!A:A,$B2),"")` to pull the data from the first column
- Copy this formula across to column G
- Copy all of these down the sheet to however many rows of data you would like
- Hide columns A, B and D since these will contain irrelevant information

You should then have an autoupdating table based on the date in cell `M1` on the original data sheet. As mentioned above, this can be adapted in many ways, and it may not be ideal for your situation depending on your data set size, but it may be a start for you. If it is not suitable, then please use the theory to adapt some VBA code, as this can also be done in VBA in a very similar way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But it has to be done in VBA only.So trying different logic's in Marco as i want to reduce the manual intervention in it.

Comment: Not a problem. I'll always try Excel before VBA as it is less prone to errors. I would suggest using a similar logic to the above then when coding your macro. For example, filter the table for the correct date, then for each staff id, add the time to a total if it is an "exit", subtract if it is an "entry" and if the total is less than 9 hours, save it to an array. Then go through the filtered table, and copy any rows with those staff IDs in it to the new sheet.